# MySQL : トランザクションでINSERTする際、Duplicateエラーのみ無視して処理を続けるには

Tags: mysql

カラムにはユニーク設定をしているので、INSERTはできませんが、トランザクションでINSERTし、Duplicateエラーのみ無視して、次のINSERTの処理を行う方法はありますでしょうか？

MySQL
バージョン : 5.1.73
ストレージエンジン : InnoDB

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

二つの対応方法があると思います。普通の`INSERT`の代わりに

1. [`INSERT IGNORE ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html)を使ったら、duplicateエラーが無視されます。
2. [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)を使ったら、duplicateではない場合レコードがinsertされます。duplicateである場合レコードがupdateされます。

Comment: insert ignoreでうまくいきました。ありがとうございました。